# Count the length of Chinese character in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string that includes `Chinese` characters in it. I want to calculate the length of the string but I want to count 1 `Chinese` character equals to 3 characters.

Here are the strings and how I am counting length of strings.

```
SELECT LENGTH ('510-000897(PHCS-DS020G1EBONG-A231) on 0524 no cap ( all upper pin to 2.5mm , all') FROM dual

SELECT LENGTH ('510-000897(PHCS-DS020G1EBONG-A231)承認書.pdf') FROM dual
```

The first string returns `length = 80` while the second string returns `length = 41`.
But what I want is it should return length of second string `= 47` as there are 3 `Chinese` characters in the string and 1 should be equal to 3 so the length should be `47`.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to length in Unicode characters you should use LENGTHC function.

```
SELECT LENGTHC('510-000897(PHCS-DS020G1EBONG-A231)承認書.pdf') FROM dual

LENGTHC('510-000897(PHCS-DS020G1EBONG-A231)?????????.PDF')
----------------------------------------------------------
                            47
```

Comment: Great, now I want to select first 45 characters from this string considering there are 47 characters in this string. How do I do that ? I know I should be asking another question but I just wanted to get over with it. If you don't mind helping here.

Comment: `SUBSTRC` should do the job: `SELECT SUBSTRC('510-000897(PHCS-DS020G1EBONG-A231)承認書.pdf',1, 45) FROM dual;`

Comment: You're a life savior. Appreciate it